# swimlane/ngx-datatable doesn't work after update to 16.0.3 (columns seem to be the problem)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

So I have updated my application to angular 9 and with that I updated ngx-datatable from version 16.0.2 to 16.0.3. But now my columns stay empty. Everything worked fine a minor version before. No errors, no warning. Here is the simplifed code I use to fill my columns.

component.ts:

```
  columns = [
        { name: 'Vertragsnummer', prop: 'VertragsNr', flexGrow: 6 },
        { name: 'Risiko', prop: 'RisikoAllgemein', flexGrow: 10 },
        { name: 'Sparte', prop: 'Sparte', flexGrow: 5 },
        { name: 'Gesellschaft', prop: 'Vu', flexGrow: 10 },
        { name: 'Ablauf', prop: 'Vertragsablauf', flexGrow: 4 }
      ];
```

component.html:

```
   <ngx-datatable
  *ngIf="columns"
  class="material afn-flat-table"
  #datatable
  [rows]="(rows$ | async) || []"
  [columns]="columns"
  [columnMode]="'flex'"
  [headerHeight]="60"
  [footerHeight]="30"
  [rowHeight]="30"
  [count]="liste.length"
  [limit]="limit"
  [selected]="selected"
  [selectionType]="'row'"
  [messages]="messages"
  (select)="onSelect($event)"
  (sort)="onSort($event)"
> 
<div *ngFor="let column of columns">
    {{asdf(column)}}
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="{{ column.prop }}" name="{{ column.name }}" [flexGrow]="column.flexGrow">
      <ng-template let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn" ngx-datatable-header-template>
        <div name="firsrowheader" (click)="sort()">
          <span *ngIf="sorts[0]?.prop == column.prop">
            <mat-icon class="fas asf-gridSortIcon" [ngClass]="{ 'fa-sort-up': sorts[0].dir === 'asc', 'fa-sort-down': sorts[0].dir === 'desc' }">
            </mat-icon>
          </span>
          <label i18n style="height:10px;cursor:pointer" class="columnlabel">{{ column.name }}</label>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
  </div>
</ngx-datatable>
```

I am logging the columns and they are all correct but aren't rendered and all this results in an empty table: 
[image]

I left out a lot of code here, and just included what I think could be a part of the problem. I didn't find any indication that the column specification changed. The rows are there, otherwise I wouldn't see the icon in the first row.

If you need further information just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I’ve seen it doesn’t yet support angular 9. I stopped the upgrade on our project when I got the warning about incompatibility with ngx-datatable.

The better question is when they’re planning to release an update for compatibility! It’s been months.

ETA: 4 days later they started some new releases! 17.0.0 is strictly compatible with angular 9.